# Volley. How to stop / cancel a working POST request?

Tags: android, android-volley

How to stop / cancel a working POST request?

I use VolleyPlus.

Eg i click "Send" button and calling

```
    SimpleMultiPartRequest jsonRequest = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST......
    ...

    jsonRequest.setTag(TAG);
    jsonRequest.addFile("image", String.valueOf(outputFile.getAbsoluteFile()));
    jsonRequest.setFixedStreamingMode(true);
    mRequestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

And image started uploading... And on 50% upload i thought change image and click "Cancel":

```
            .onAny(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    Log.e("cancel", "cancel");
                    if (mRequestQueue != null) mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
                //        mRequestQueue.stop();
                }
            })
```

But the upload process continues (

Comment: Are you sure, you are even entering into the `onClick()`?

Comment: Yes, i see "E/cancel: cancel" in console.

Comment: are you like displaying a dialog whenever you start uploading data?

Comment: Dialog with progressbar, show uploading process in percent

Comment: and, did you see the reflection of it on your server too? There is a possibility that Volley actually stopped the service request but you are failing to update your UI.

Comment: On the server in tcpflow I see the traffic, and server script fulfills at the end of loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155695/discussion-between-dennis-and-serg).